Why have Uncaught Snapshot missing error with slot components of 2 types?
On laravel 11 site I use on the form volt components defined as resources/views/livewire/common/controls/input_text.blade.php :
<?php

use Livewire\Volt\Component;
use Livewire\Attributes\Modelable;

new class extends Component {
    #[Modelable]
    public $form;
    public string $formattedValue = '';
    public string $fieldName = '';
    public string $label = '';
    public ?string $placeholder = '';
    public ?int $maxlength = 0;
    public ?int $tabindex = 0;
};
?>

<div class="editor_field_block_wrapper d2">

    <div class="">
        <div class="w-4/12 pb-0 pl-2 md:pt-3 ">
            <label for="{{ $fieldName }}" class="">
                {{ !empty($label) ? $label: \Str::ucfirst(\Str::replace('_', ' ', $fieldName)) }}:
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="p-2 w-full">
            <input id="{{ $fieldName }}" name="{{ $fieldName }}" type="text"
                   class="editor_form_input"
                   @if(!empty($maxlength)) maxlength="{{ $maxlength }}" @endif
                   wire:model="form.{{ $fieldName }}"
                   autocomplete="off"
                   @if(!empty($placeholder)) placeholder="{{ $placeholder }}" @endif
                   @if(!empty($tabindex)) tabindex="{{ $tabindex }}" @endif/>
            @error('form.' . $fieldName)
            <span class="error_text">{{$message}}</span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

and resources/views/livewire/common/controls/input_readonly.blade.php (I tried to use :key= in any "div" element like I read at https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/troubleshooting#adding-wirekey ):
<?php

use Livewire\Volt\Component;
use function Livewire\Volt\{mount, state};

state(['fieldName'=> '', 'form'=> '']);
new class extends Component {
    public $form = [];
    public $fieldName = '';

} ?>

<div class="editor_field_block_wrapper d1"  :key="$fieldName . 'RootDivReadonly'">


    <div class=""  :key="$fieldName . 'SplitterDivReadonly'">
        <div class="w-4/12 pb-0 pl-2 md:pt-3">
            <label for="{{ $fieldName }}" class="">
                {{ \Str::ucfirst($fieldName) }}:
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="p-2 w-full"  :key="$fieldName . 'ParentDivReadonly'">
            <input
                id="{{ $fieldName }}" name="{{ $fieldName }}" type="text"
                value="{{ $form->{$fieldName} }}"
                tabindex="-1"
                :key="$fieldName . 'Readonly'"
                readonly/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

on the form I se both type controls :
<form class="form-editor" wire:submit="update" enctype="multipart/form-data">


    <livewire:common.controls.input_readonly fieldName="id" :form="$form" :key="'idReadonly'"  />


    <livewire:common.controls.input_text fieldName="phone" wire:model="form" :maxlength="100" tabindex="10" :key="'phoneInputText'" />

    <livewire:common.controls.input_text fieldName="website" wire:model="form" :maxlength="50" tabindex="20" placeholder="Fill your website url" :key="'websiteInputText'" />


</form>

Problem is that after I edit data in input_text elements and save the form I got error :
in Uncaught Snapshot missing on Livewire component with id: 2MfhLF0gKp6I1w1LtNDh

and my form is broken.
If I remove line with
<livewire:common.controls.input_readonly
    

component (it is the only on the form)  - I have no this error and form is saved ok.
What is wrong in my code and how to fix it ?
"laravel/framework": "^11.9",
"livewire/livewire": "^3.5",
"livewire/volt": "^1.6",

UPDATES :
I remade resources/views/livewire/common/controls/input_readonly.blade.php file :
<?php

use function Livewire\Volt\{state};

state(['fieldName'=> '', 'form'=> '']);

?>

<div wire:key="$fieldName . 'RootDivReadonly'">
    
    <div   wire:key="$fieldName . 'SplitterDivReadonly'">
        <div class="w-4/12 pb-0 pl-2 md:pt-3">
            <label for="{{ $fieldName }}" >
                {{ \Str::ucfirst($fieldName) }}:
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="p-2 w-full"  wire:key="$fieldName . 'ParentDivReadonly'">
            <input
                id="{{ $fieldName }}" name="{{ $fieldName }}" type="text"
                value="{{ $form->{$fieldName} }}"
                tabindex="-1"
                wire:key="$fieldName . 'Readonly'"
                readonly/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

But still got the same error when I save the form. No error on page opened.
Did I define wire:key correctly ?
Please provide a link to functional API manuals...
UPDATES 2:
Here https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/alpine#refreshing-a-component I found :

You can easily refresh a Livewire component (trigger network roundtrip
to re-render a component's Blade view) using $wire.$refresh():

I try to use it as in my blade file I have :
    <form class="form-editor" wire:submit="update" enctype="multipart/form-data">


    <livewire:common.controls.input_readonly fieldName="id" :form="$form" :key="'idReadonly'"  />


    <livewire:common.controls.input_text fieldName="phone" wire:model="form" :maxlength="100" tabindex="10" :key="'phoneInputText'" />

    <livewire:common.controls.input_text fieldName="website" wire:model="form" :maxlength="50" tabindex="20" placeholder="Fill your website url" :key="'websiteInputText'" />

</form>
I tried to use $refresh method in the parent livewire component :


use Livewire\Component;

class ProfileEditor extends Component
{

    public function update(Request $request)
    {

        try {
            $user = User::findOrFail($this->form->id);
        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
            return;
        }

        $user->phone = $this->form->phone;
        $user->website = $this->form->website;
        ...

        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();
            $user->save();
            DB::commit();

            $this->refresh(); // I added this method.

But I got runtime error :
Run time error : 

Method App\Livewire\Personal\ProfileEditor::refresh does not exist.

How to use this method, as in blade file the form is submitted with " wire:submit="update" instruction ?
UPDATES 3:
I try to use both ways :

In component ProfileEditor I dispatched the event after data are saved:
$user->save();
$this->dispatch('profileEditorSaved', ['id' => $this->form->id]);


and in blade file I catch this event :
<div>
        ...
                    <form class="form-editor" wire:submit="update" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <livewire:common.controls.input_readonly fieldName="id" :form="$form" :key="'idReadonly'"  />

                        <livewire:common.controls.input_text fieldName="phone" wire:model="form" :maxlength="100" tabindex="10" :key="'phoneInputText'" />

                        <livewire:common.controls.input_text fieldName="website" wire:model="form" :maxlength="50" tabindex="20" placeholder="Fill your website url" :key="'websiteInputText'" />
                        ...
                    </form>


    @script
    <script>


        // This event listener updates the component with all childs
        $wire.on("profileEditorSaved", ($options) => {
            console.log('profileEditorSaved $options::')
            console.log($options)

            $wire.$refresh();
        });

    </script>
    @endscript


</div>

After data are saved I see in the browser's console output of profileEditorSaved event, but next
the same error :
Uncaught Snapshot missing on Livewire component with id: VNoy1hE2mxNE9ewZ4T5O


Not shure how to implement it. I tried to modify input_readonly.blade.php as :
use function Livewire\Volt{state};
state(['fieldName'=> '', 'form'=> '']);
 <div class="editor_field_block_device_splitter"  wire:key="SplitterDivReadonly-{{rand()}}">
     <div class="w-4/12 pb-0 pl-2 md:pt-3">
         <label for="{{ $fieldName }}" class="editor_field_block_device_label">
             {{ \Str::ucfirst($fieldName) }}:
         </label>
     </div>
     <div class="p-2 w-full"  wire:key="ParentDivReadonly-{{rand()}}">
         <input
             id="{{ $fieldName }}" name="{{ $fieldName }}" type="text"
             class="editor_form_readonly"
             value="{{ $form->{$fieldName} }}"
             tabindex="-1"
             wire:key="Readonly-{{rand()}}"
             readonly/>
     </div>
 </div>



But still the same error!
Did I understand you correctly!
Thanks in advance!

I think the problem might be related to mixed Volt API.
To declare variable you should either use functional API:
state(['fieldName'=> '', 'form'=> '']);

Or class API:
new class extends Component {
    public $form = [];
    public $fieldName = '';
}

Do not mix this, because it's completely different approaches. Functional API creates class under the hood, while with traditional class-based components you declare it explicit.
Also, you shouldn't use :key, but wire:key with html elements.
For example
<livewire:some-component :key="unique-component-key"/>

<div wire:key="unique-key"></div>

Update. I checked your demo app. When I removed all wire:key attributes and refresh event listener, the issue is gone.
<?php

use function Livewire\Volt\{state};

state(['fieldName' => '', 'form' => '']);

?>

<div class="">
    <div class="">
        <div class="w-4/12 pb-0 pl-2 md:pt-3">
            <label for="{{ $fieldName }}" class="">
                {{ \Str::ucfirst($fieldName) }}:
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="p-2 w-full">
            <input
                id="{{ $fieldName }}" name="{{ $fieldName }}" type="text"
                style="border:1px dotted"
                value="{{ $form->{$fieldName} }}"
                tabindex="-1"
                readonly
            />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

You can also remove dispatching event from your component.
$this->dispatch('saved');


Please read UPDATES

Functional API: https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/volt#api-style

Thanks! I reviewed the docs and still do not see what can be wrong in my code? Please check - I edited misformatting in my code

I cannot say, where is the problem exactly, but I see some mistakes in code, which could be related to this. For example, your wire:key. This is an html attribute, so instead of this <div wire:key="$fieldName . 'RootDivReadonly'"> you should use something like this wire:key="{{ $fieldName }}-RootDivReadonly"

I tried and it did not help. Any other ideas ?

I would recommend not to create separate livewire components for simple logic like inputs. The same results you can achieve using blade components and just adding attributes like wire:model to them. https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/blade

Using livewire components  with blade components has some problems, imho. Using of  livewire components in all app has some advantage I suppose

If there is a way after submit is called to refresh current components with all  subcomponents ?

Please read UPDATES 2

$refresh magic method for some reason is available only on AlpineJS. You have two options. You can listen for refresh event using $wire.on and in event use $wire.$refresh. But I would recommend another way. Add some dynamics to your wire:key. The simplest example is wire:key="rand()", but you should add some prefix for key. If the key was changed, then Livewire think that it should re-render this part of HTML.

Please read UPDATES 3

Hmmm. Try to use alpine js listeners instead of script. add @profileEditorSaved.window="" event listener to your div in parent component. https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/events#listening-for-livewire-events-in-alpine

Could you please to detalize with example last message ?

Add event listener to the main element<div @saved.window="$wire.$refresh()"></div>.
And call this event $this->dispatch('saved'); in your component class.

I try your way. 1) With code :
<div class=""  wire:key="{{ $fieldName }}-RootDivReadonly" @saved.window="$wire.$refresh();  alert('REFRESHED');">
I got alert message (checked event is triggered) - but the same error!
2) I tried to remove            wire:key= in this (and others divs) - the same result

Okey. Try to call this $this->js('$wire.$refresh()'); instead of dispatching event, maybe this will help.

Did not help anyway

I create a demo project at https://github.com/PetroGromovo/Laravel11Demo with standart installation. Please check.

I added 50 point by bounty on this issue salved

I make an update in my comment. Check this changes locally.

I try to follow your instruction and failed with the same error.

I removed all wire:key from input_readonly.blade.php
If I removed dispatching event from my component
$this->dispatch('saved');
have I to use $wire.$refresh(); in input_readonly.blade.php
You did not show it. Sorry, very confused. Could you, please, to push modified changes to github?


No, you don't need $wire.$refresh() in input_readonly.blade.php. Just use that view file, which I add in "Update" section.

I copypasted code from your "Update" section into resources/views/livewire/common/controls/input_readonly.blade.php - just the same error. In this version we do not any seetings you wrote about last messages ?

https://gist.github.com/vkarchevskyi/a3304ffbce4cd8030523df3bc0afff6f
